# SIP server на java с использованием Datagram

Tags: java, сервер, sip

Есть готовый сервер на java с использованием Datagram https://github.com/srajat/UDP-SIP-Server 
но он то падает, потому что строки парсит неправильно, то запросы шлет не такие как надо, где найти пример нормальный?

Comment: Что про это говорит автор сервера?